# Node on the side of a horizontal tree

Tags: tikz-trees, logic

I am struggling to understand how to put a node on the branch of the first level of a tree of bernoulli trials. When I try to draw it out, the node label in the center of the branch becomes the starting point of my children nodes. Could anyone please provide some suggestions?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 [font=\footnotesize,
       grow=right, level 1/.style={sibling distance=6em},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=1em}, level distance=5cm] 
\node (Root) {} % root
 child { node {s} edge from parent node [below = .25cm] {$\frac{1}{2}$}
    child { node {s} edge from parent node [above = .25cm] {$\frac{1}{2}$}} 
    child { node {f} edge from parent node [below = .25cm] {$\frac{1}{2}$}}
 }
 child { node {f}
    child { node {s} edge from parent node [above = .25cm] {$\frac{1}{2}$}} 
    child { node {f} edge from parent node [below = .25cm] {$\frac{1}{2}$}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nice question, but if you could supplement the code with a header that makes it compilable, it would be even better.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: You can add the `edge from parent node` key *after* the two children. If I understand you correctly, you should add `edge from parent node {...}` on lines 9 and 13 of your current code snippet.

Comment: @HerrK, the problem I am facing is that whenever I try to add the node on the first branch from the root, my next branches become rooted at the branch label instead of the end of the branch, the s or f.

Comment: @mccraig23 No need to be sorry! `:-)` I added an image of the output.

Answer (score 3):

In a TikZ tree, to modify the branch (e.g. change its color, add text, and/or other styles) from a parent node (say `P`) to its child (say `C1`), you have to place the `edge from parent` key after `C1` and all children and grandchildren of `C1`.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 [font=\footnotesize,
       grow=right, level 1/.style={sibling distance=6em},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=1em}, level distance=5cm] 
\node (Root) {} % root
 child { node {s} 
    child { node {s} edge from parent node [above = .25cm] {$\frac{1}{2}$}} 
    child { node {f} edge from parent node [below = .25cm] {$\frac{1}{2}$}}
    edge from parent node [below = .25cm] {$\frac{1}{2}$} % NEW
 }
 child { node {f}
    child { node {s} edge from parent node [above = .25cm] {$\frac{1}{2}$}} 
    child { node {f} edge from parent node [below = .25cm] {$\frac{1}{2}$}}
    edge from parent node [above = .25cm] {$\frac{1}{2}$} % NEW
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I'd give you a thumbs up, but my level is too low :P

Comment: Im still working through reading the manual to learn more, but could you provide any insight to why you needed to place that command where you did?

Comment: @mccraig23: I'm glad I can help. I added some explanation to my answer.